# What is strictly well-ordered under $\in$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

I am studying from a set of notes (otherwise quite excellent) which does not explicitly specify some definitions of "ordering."

I have tried to accumulate the various pieces from various discussions and proofs in the text, but am having a hard time putting them together.

In one place it says *strictly well-orderered by $\in$* is $n\lt m$ iff $n\in m$.

In another it says a *well-ordered set* is totally ordered in which every non-empty set has a minimal element. And one aspect of the definition of *total ordering* is that inequality satisfied by "*minimal*" is "weak" ($\leq$) rather than "strict" ($\lt$).

Lastly, one of the two features of the definition of an *ordinal* is that it is  *strictly well-orderered by $\in$*.

> > M confusion comes in a proof showing that an $\alpha$ is an ordinal because "it has a minimal element and *thus is well-ordered under $\in$*." Whereas, the definition of an ordinal says nothing about a minimal element. Are they the same thing?
> >
> > And why does it not say: *strictly* well-ordered by $\in$?

I know this is probably torturous reading this and I've tried to be as clear as possible. Perhaps it would be easier to suggest a reference where these aspects are delineated. I've tried wikipedia and several well-known texts.

Thanks

Comment: Is the double negation on purpose?

Comment: @AsafKaragila fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why your notes say what they say. Often notes are written when giving a course, and it is often convenient in introductory courses to talk about non-strict orders, and then when you reach well-orders it is necessary to talk about strict orders, and the definitions become cumbersome.

How do I know all that? Because five years ago I made that same mistake.

So we say that a set $\alpha$ is an ordinal if it is *transitive* and strictly well-ordered by the $\in$ relation. And for two ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$ we write $\alpha<\beta$ if $\alpha\in\beta$.

It is necessary to require that the well-order is strict, since otherwise if we do not assume the Axiom of Regularity, it is possible that there is some $x=\{x\}$, which is then certainly a transitive set which is well-ordered by $\in$. But it is not strictly well-ordered by $\in$, since $x\in x$. And it is also necessary to assume that the set is transitive, since every singleton $x$ such that $x\neq\{x\}$ is strictly well-ordered by $\in$, whereas you want your universe to have exactly one ordinal which is a singleton.

Comment: If we don’t assume the well order is strict won’t $2$ not be an ordinal, since $1\in1$ is false.

Comment: Isn't it lucky, then, that we *do* assume that well-orders are strict?

Comment: So just to clarify then that the axiom of regularity isn’t relevant here correct?

Comment: Yes, it is not relevant. I will note that some people will define well-orders to be also reflexive, but when talking about the ordinals *we always* assume strict orders are involved. My answer here explains why.

Comment: Isn’t adding transitive also superfluous since transitivity is a partial order axiom. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, because "transitive set" is relative to the universe, not a property of the relation per se.